Orgmode change font color of equations
I am hoping I can change the color of font that is in equations, but I am not sure how. Any help is appreciated.
For example "area of circle is $\pi r^2$" the part inside the $$ would hopefully be yellow while "area of circle is" would be white.
When I do M-x "describe-face" on an org file it is just the default face; however, auto-expanding snippets knows when the text is in a math environment, so I think it should be possible.
For completeness, a LaTeX file uses the face font-latex-math-face for text inside of math environment, so this is easy to change.

Customize org-highlight-latex-and-related, enable it and turn on the LaTeX snippets and environments (native) option. The doc string of the variable says (do C-h v org-highlight-latex-and-related to see it:
org-highlight-latex-and-related is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.

Its value is (native script entities)
Original value was nil

Non-nil means highlight LaTeX related syntax in the buffer.
When non-nil, the value should be a list containing any of the
following symbols:
  ‘native’   Highlight LaTeX snippets and environments natively.
  ‘latex’    Highlight LaTeX snippets and environments.
  ‘script’   Highlight subscript and superscript.
  ‘entities’ Highlight entities.

  This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
  version 24.4 of Emacs.
  You can customize this variable.



Thanks so much! Dunno how I missed this variable...
